# $\sigma(C_1) \subset \sigma(C_2) \iff C_1 \subset C_2$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space and $C_1, C_2 \subset \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. Then, [we](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623532/if-d-1-subseteq-d-2-then-the-generated-sigma-algebras-are-such-that-sigmad) [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557758/mathcalc-1-subseteq-mathcalc-2-implies-sigma-mathcalc-1-subseteq?noredirect=1&lq=1) that $C_1 \subset C_2 \implies \sigma(C_1) \subset \sigma(C_2)$, where
>   $$
> \sigma(A) 
> := \bigcap \{ \mathcal{B}: \mathcal{B} \text{ is a } \sigma\text{-algebra containing } A \}
> $$
>   is the generated $\sigma$-algebra of $A \subset \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.
>   Does the converse also hold?

Since in our lecture, we only formulated one direction, I would be surprised if both directions worked, but haven't been able to come up with a counterexample.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume here your "$\subset$" means "$\subseteq$" (containment) and not "$\subsetneq$" (proper containment).

Assuming this, then it's not true. Suppose $S$ is an element of $\sigma(C_2)$ which is not actually already in $C_2$, and define $C_1 = C_2\cup \{S\}$.

Then $\sigma(C_1)=\sigma(C_2)$, so $ \sigma(C_1)\subset \sigma(C_2)$, but $C_1\not\subset C_2$.

Comment: Is the following a good example? $\Omega := \{ 0,1,2\}$, $C_1 := \{ \{1\}, \{2\}, \{0\} \}$ and $C_2 := \{ \{1,2\}, \{0,2\}, \{0,1\}\}$?  Then, clearly, $C_1 \not\subset C_2$, but $\sigma(C_1)  = \sigma(C_2) = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\Omega := \mathbb{R}, \ C_1 := \{ A \subset \Omega: A \text{ open} \}$ and $C_2 := \{ A \subset \Omega: A \text{ closed} \}$.
Then, $\sigma(C_1) = \sigma(C_2) = \mathcal{B}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel-$\sigma$-Algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, and therefore, $\sigma(C_1) \subset \sigma(C_2)$ but $C_1 \not\subset C_2$.